# Select data from 2 tables with linking attribute value of 3rd table

Tags: php, mysql

Table `payment` has as `FK{exchange_order_id}` the id of `exchange_order` and `payment_info` has as `FK{payment_id}` the id of `payment`. So, **payment_info** and **exchange_order** don't have any shared attribute, but I need data from them, and that's why I am trying to query them through the **payment** table which is the only link in-between.

I am trying to pull records for a certain time period, therefore I don't know the `payment.id` attribute.

I get error `near 'FROM exchange_order eo, payment_info pi JOIN payment p ON p.exchange_order_id = ' at line 6`

```
SELECT
 eo.amount_proposed as proposed,
 eo.amount_realized as realized,
 pi.local_fee as fee,
 pi.local_market_rate as market_rate,
  FROM exchange_order eo, payment_info pi
JOIN payment p ON p.exchange_order_id = eo.id
JOIN payment_info ON p.id = pi.payment_id 
WHERE create_time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-09-01') AND create_time < UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-10-01')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** first remove extra `,` after `pi.local_market_rate as market_rate` from select statement that is the main reason for the error.

```
SELECT
 eo.amount_proposed as proposed,
 eo.amount_realized as realized,
 pi.local_fee as fee,
 pi.local_market_rate as market_rate
  FROM exchange_order eo
JOIN payment p ON p.exchange_order_id = eo.id
JOIN payment_info pi ON p.id = pi.payment_id 
WHERE create_time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-09-01') AND create_time < UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-10-01')
```

Comment: Yeah, I simply copied your solution, to be sure I don't mistake something again. Still doesn't work.

Comment: after  pi.local_market_rate as market_rate there is a comma just remove and run from your sql or in my updated one.

Comment: yep. I don't get errors, but I get empty result. I tried simply `select * from exchange_order where create_time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-09-01') AND create_time < UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-10-01')` just to see if the problem is in the timestamps, but it isn't.

Comment: that means the qualifying records are not there ,please do a cross check.try with left join and see if it gives some records or not just for the test.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a comma between two table names in this line:

```
     FROM exchange_order eo, payment_info pi
```

Don't you need a JOIN of some kind with an ON clause of some kind?

Answer (score 0):

You cant write it like that, if you write

```
exchange_order eo, payment_info pi
JOIN payment p
```

to sql it cant know if you mean

```
 (exchange_order eo, payment_info pi)
JOIN payment p
```

or

```
 exchange_order eo, (payment_info pi
JOIN payment p)
```

I am pretty sure you cant use both comma and join in a same FROM in sql.